# SublimeREPL for SublimeText 3 Ctrl , , + F

Tags: sublime-text-3

I use Sublime Text 3 with SublimeREPL on Windows.

When I use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> it works sometimes but most of the time it doesn't work.

What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcut "Ctrl,,+F" step is

1. Pressing the <kbd>,</kbd> key while holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.
2. Releasing all of them at the same time.
3. Click <kbd>F</kbd>.

The second comma just means the shortcut has two parts, don't click <kbd>,</kbd> twice.